# Blender place holder mesh data - need help, mesh is resizing

Tags: blender, mesh, terrain, particles

Currently using Blender V2.67

I'm following a tutorial at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SUcpgDVBLDQ&list=SP9FE4ACC7E521FBBF Around 17:00 is when it starts explaining what I'm attempting to do. 20:05-22:30 Shows how to make a low-poly place holder. At 22:24 he changes the mesh of the object from the low-poly place holder to the mesh of the palm tree.

When I change the mesh of the low-res place holder object to the mesh of the "hi-res" palm tree mesh it automatically makes the palm tree like 1/100 the original size and makes anything I use almost invisible.  Now, when I make a "hi-res" objects mesh to that of the low-res place holder's mesh, I get the low-res mesh but it is gigantic, the opposite of making a low-res object's mesh a "hi-res" mesh. How do I fix this? In the video when he changes the mesh it stays the same dimension.

Answer (score 0):

I scaled the object in object mode instead of edit mode which changed the scale size instead of the dimensions.